# I have Alphabetic pageination page. I want getting an every alphabetic post list onclick on letter in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress,I want I have Alphabetic pageination page. I want getting an every alphabetic post list onclick on letter in wordpress?
please any one can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=5&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-posts-in-ascending-order